# German equivalent to "same as last time" for making appointments

Tags: english-to-german, time, spoken-language

In English, when scheduling a meeting or deciding when to meet with someone, one often says "same as last time". For example:

> At what time should we go jogging tomorrow? - Same as last time, at 4pm.

What would be the most natural equivalent to this in German? Good translations of spoken language and expressions are hard to find in a dictionary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could simply say

> Wieder um 4. 
> *(4 again.)*

or

> Gleiche Zeit wie gestern, 16 Uhr. 
> *(Same time as yesterday, 4pm.)*

or just<sup>1</sup>

> Wie letztes Mal: um 4. 
> *(Like last time.)*

If you met already more than once and always at 4pm:

> Wie immer: um 4. 
> *(As always: 4.)*

---

<sup>1) as @userunknown suggested in the comments</sup>

Comment: Wieso nicht "wie letztes Mal"?

Comment: @userunknown Ja, natürlich! Vielen Dank!